# How to initialize widget in component VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Do as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508390/how-to-initialize-widget-in-component-vue), but unfortunately something goes wrong.
I want to initializate [this](https://vk.com/js/api/share.js?93) code.
This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="vk_share_button"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      methods:{
        start(){
          document.getElementById('vk_share_button').innerHTML =
            VK.Share.button('example.com', {type: 'link'});
        }
      },
      created(){
          VK.ready(this.start());
      }
    }
</script>
```

Also I tried to use: VK.Share.ready/VK.Share.button.ready, but I get the same error:

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I thought that the external code isn't loaded, but I not sure. Where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) block instead of [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) block, as mounted  block is *Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el*`, like following:

```
<script>
    export default {
      methods:{
        start(){
          document.getElementById('vk_share_button').innerHTML =
            VK.Share.button('example.com', {type: 'link'});
        }
      },
      mounted(){
          VK.ready(this.start());
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have another proplem on console: VK.ready is not a function. But it works. How can I improve it?

Comment: Looks like there's no such method `ready`. You can just do   mounted(){ this.start(); } in order to insert a button.